# How Can automatically run a command by clicking a file instead of typing it out each time?

Tags: cmd.exe, automation

So i want to display all local IP-addresses in CMD simply by running a file..
instead of typing

`ipconfig | find /i "IPv4"` each time

I know there was a way but I forgot..

Or just link me the file so i can download..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Create a Batch File (Simple Script)**

Make a Bat file and name it what ever you want

Example: **Test.bat**

then open test.bat file in notepad and put in the command you want

example:

```
ipconfig | find /i "IPv4"

pause
```

(Use pause to stop the script from closing)

then save it as the .bat file, double click and it will run

Comment: ooohh.. I did not know about that "pause"  thing...     very valuable information

Comment: You can also create a shortcut that simply runs the command `cmd.exe /c ipconfig /all | find /i “IPV4” && pause`. You do that by creating a shortcut and selecting cmd.exe as the program to run and putting the rest of the command as the parameter.